# What does wc -w do in an echo and tr command?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm currently approaching Linux and stumbled upon something I don't really understand.

I have a already stated command going:

`echo "12345"|wc –w|tr "123" "321"`

The output of this command is `3`, so I thought that it might count how many of these numbers have change, but after some testing I came up with a conclusion that in fact it shows the first number in second tr argument, since it worked in many cases.

For a while I thought I was done with my experiments since I got the whole idea, but I've found a specific case:

`echo "46817"|wc -w|tr "46817" "64194"` which outputs in `9` and I don't have any idea why.

What does the whole command outputs in not certain cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last command **tr** changes numbers in the score of second command. So as **wc** command counts words in first argument (is equal to 1) than last command changes intiger 1 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

> echo "12345"|wc –w|tr "123" "321"   (outputs 3)
>   echo "46817"|wc -w|tr "46817" "64194"   (outputs 9)

The above commands are *pipes* in which the output of each command is fed to the next one. Commands are separated by "|" (symbol named, surprise!, "pipe"). Both commands do:

echo: outputs something (to wc).

wc: counts characters, or words, or lines. "wc -w" counts words, so it will output "1" because "12345" and "46817" are words not containing any word separator.

tr: "translates", i.e. changes the characters it receives with other ones. When specifying `"123" "321"` the 1's (first char in 123) is translated in 3 (the first char of 321); the 2's (second char in 123) are translated into 2 (second char in 321) and so on.

In both commands `tr` receives "1" as input, and turns that "1" in some other character.